Should I Use AWS Timestream Scheduled Queries or Pre-Calculate Aggregates for Time-Series Data?
I’m working with AWS Timestream to store IoT sensor data that includes measurements like temperature, humidity, etc. My use case involves collecting data from sensors every hour, and I need to calculate daily averages for reporting and analytics purposes.
Here’s an example of the query I’m using to calculate the daily averages for a specific sensor over a week:
const params = {
QueryString: `
SELECT
bin(time, 1d) AS day,
AVG(measure_value::double) AS daily_avg
FROM "iot"."test"
WHERE
        AND sensor_id = '${sensorId}' 
        AND time BETWEEN TIMESTAMP '${startWeek} 00:00:00' 
        AND TIMESTAMP '${endWeek} 23:59:59' 
    GROUP BY bin(time, 1d)  
    ORDER BY day ASC
`

};
const data = await timestreamquery.query(params).promise();
Problem:
I am debating between two approaches for calculating and storing these daily averages:

Pre-calculating the averages: Every time data is ingested, I could calculate the average and store it in a separate table for faster querying.
Using AWS Timestream's Scheduled Queries: I could run scheduled queries (e.g., once a day) to calculate and store daily averages in a different table.

My Questions:

Which approach is considered best practice in terms of performance and cost-efficiency, especially as the volume of data grows?
Are there any other common solutions that I should consider for this type of problem (e.g., Lambda functions for real-time aggregation, Athena, or a combination of approaches)?
What are some potential challenges I might face with either solution, particularly when dealing with real-time vs. historical data aggregation?
My Requirements:


Data volume: I expect a high volume of hourly sensor data.
Real-time monitoring: I would like the ability to get near-real-time aggregated data if possible.
Cost-efficiency: Minimizing both query and storage costs is important.
Any advice on the best approach or alternative solutions would be much appreciated!

Current Approach: I am currently running a query similar to the one below to calculate daily averages when needed:
const params = {
QueryString: `
SELECT
bin(time, 1d) AS day,
AVG(measure_value::double) AS daily_avg
FROM "iot"."test"
WHERE
        AND sensor_id = '${sensorId}' 
        AND time BETWEEN TIMESTAMP '${startWeek} 00:00:00' 
        AND TIMESTAMP '${endWeek} 23:59:59' 
    GROUP BY bin(time, 1d)  
    ORDER BY day ASC
`

};
const data = await timestreamquery.query(params).promise();
I was expecting this to work well for getting daily averages. However, as the data grows, I am concerned that querying large datasets frequently for real-time dashboards could become slow and expensive.
Planned Approach: I’m considering two options:

Pre-calculating averages on data ingestion and storing them in a separate table, expecting this would make querying faster and more efficient.
Using AWS Timestream’s Scheduled Queries to calculate and store daily averages once per day, expecting this would help me avoid the overhead of real-time calculations.


To start, I would suggest you to do small PoCs with the options you have and research their cost, easiness to implement and how easy to maintain it is, together with business requirements.
Having said that, scheduled queries will do what you need quite easily and, if you metrics/dimensions are well set, the cost won't be a huge problem, as the queries will read only the data indexed for the day and will spit out, probably, a single row with the aggregated data you need. I would advise using it if your requirements for "live information" are flexible to one day time span.
If you need real data (like, last 24hs avg), then scheduled queries are probably not what you need. Maybe you could use something like Apache Flink to read your packages and calculate the avg in a windowed way and store it somewhere else. But I would advise that using Flink just for daily averages is, in my humble opinion, over-engineering.
